# Is there a straightforward way to convert a WPF .NET Framework application to UWP .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core, uwp

I have some working code that I wrote awhile back that I now need again, however it uses WPF and .NET Framework rather than the required .NET Core and UWP. I've got it  to compile -- the trouble is that a lot of the bindings seem to work completely differently in UWP and break.

My question is, is there a more straightforward way of doing this rather than going through each problem area and attempting to correct it?

Comment: UWP is its own monster. Why don't you migrate to WPF on .NET Core 3?

Comment: The normal Bindings should work exactly the same way. Set a view's DataContext, bind to any property of the DataContext object. We can't tell why your Bindings don't seem to work.

Comment: *Is there a more straightforward way of doing this rather than going through each problem area and attempting to correct it?* Short answer: No, there isn't, unless you simply want to *pack* and install your WPF app as a UWP app. What's the reason for the conversion?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a straightforward way to convert a WPF .NET Framework application to UWP .NET Core?

For your requirement, you could use `Desktop Bridge` to convert win32 app to uwp. For detail setps please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-extend).